# Strange behavior of Set4 in scala 2.9.1?

Tags: scala, migration, scala-2.8, scala-2.9

Making a migration from 2.8.1 to 2.9.1 found interesting thing.
Tried to write this in console:

```
>>import collection.immutable.Set.Set4
>>new Set4[Int](1,2,3,4)
```

It gives:

```
java.lang.Error: Unexpected New
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolTable.abort(SymbolTable.scala:34)
    at scala.tools.nsc.backend.icode.GenICode$ICodePhase.scala$tools$nsc$bac
..........................
That entry seems to have slain the compiler.  Shall I replayscala:660)
your session? I can re-run each line except the last one.reach(ListBuffer.scala:
[y/n]?
```

I am using Scala version 2.9.1.final (Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM, Java 1.6.0_26).
And same things happen with classes Set3 and Set2.
Are these known issues? 
Or, maybe, I am making something wrong?
 In scala 2.8.1 console it works, and returns:

```
res0: collection.immutable.Set.Set4[Int] = Set(1,2,3,4)
```

Must I report about these as bug?

Comment: Is there a reason you use `Set4` directly?

Comment: Yes, I want to have a key with four integers, that will be frequently used with Set operations(as |,&,&~), because of it wanted to have an object with optimized implementation.

Comment: `Set(1,2,3,4).isInstanceOf[collection.immutable.Set.Set4[Int]] == true` this happens automatically already.

Comment: Cool, thanks, works perfect. If there is no reason to direct call, why we could import Set2, Set3 and Set4 to scope and use them directly?

Comment: I can't think of one, except less method forwarding :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. This is a compiler bug, go ahead and report it.

Comment: (Verified on 2.10. Don't forget to post the issue number here again :D)

Comment: Thanks! If I want to participate in resolving SI bugs, how I must start?

Comment: If you really feel like you can do compiler hacking, just try debugging the issue, just as it were a bug in a project of yours, and post your results as comments to the thread.

Comment: If, instead, you want to write a more helpful bug report, you can start by giving a complete stack trace, verifying if the bug is current on a current snapshot - or at least telling the authors that it was verified by somebody.
Also, I feel like the information should be given _in_ the bug report, not through a link to this site. Extract all the relevant information (e.g. it worked on Scala 2.8.1), and only that.
See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240323/how-to-report-bugs-the-smart-way

Comment: A final possibility is that you might also start using git bisect on this repo (https://github.com/scala/scala) to discover when the bug was introduced. But that's already quite some work.